# Mouse raises the wrong window after switching windows with keys

Tags: compiz, shortcut-keys, mouse

Prelude: I have focus follows mouse, and also raise focused window.

When I switch windows with the keyboard (Alt-Tab), the new window gets focus and is raised. However, when the mouse pointer is still in some other windows, then moments later that window gets focus and will be raised instead. This makes the shortcut useless.

I remember that it used to be a bit different: The window manages used not to care about the mouse pointer’s position if the mouse remained unused after switching windows with the keys. I think that was very sensible. Is there a way to come to a similar effect now?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem. In windows, with power toys, there was a setting to have the mouse snap or move to the active window. This made this kind of problem obsolete, because whenever you raised a window with alt-tab, the mouse would automatically move to that window. I really want to be able to do this in ubuntu 11.04, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now upgraded do Oneiric Ocelot. The problem is no more. I cannot remember having changed any bit of configuration, so I assume it was in the update. For the time being, the solution is upgrading.